# How to migrate from custom encryption to Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I need to convert an app authentication to self/custom authentication over devise. The existing scheme is that we have a `secrete-key` in our codes, `salt` based in database `encrypted-password` in database. Existing scheme is using `Digest::SHA1` for encryption decryption.

What is the best way to migrate this app to `Devise`. I came to know that we can not decrypt `SHA1` hash, so its nearly impossible to convert existing data to `Devise` standard `BCrypt`.

So how should it be possible that is use existing scheme for authentication and every thing else remains the same as came from Devise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this a while ago. Hope it helps:

[Rails Custom Authentication using Devise, DataMapper, and a Legacy Database](http://www.markrichman.com/2010/11/22/rails-devise-datamapper-authentication/)

Comment: It's a pleasure! Glad I could help. PS: Did you read the bit at the bottom about the monkeys? That made me laugh.

Comment: Classic example of why [answer] says you should include the relevant sections of the linked article in your answer. This answer is now useless.